# Applying geometric transformation matrix to coordinates

Tags: matlab, image-processing, coordinate-transformation, image-registration, transformation-matrix

I want to apply geometric transformation matrix to a list of coordinates:

For example, I have two images: A and B. I use the MATLAB app 'Registration estimator' registered A (moving image) to B (fixed image), and I got a transformation matrix T.

Now I have a list of coordinates on image A, and I want to obtain the transformed coordinates on **registered image**. What should I do? Directly multiply coordinates with transformation matrix seems not working.

For example, I the image A is 200*300 pixels, and image B is 210*290 pixels. If I directly multiply transformation matrix by coordinates in image A, the calculated coordinates are also correspond to the coordinate system of A but not B. What I want is the coordinates under the coordinate system of B.

Comment: you should probably use `imwarp` to implement the transformation matrix on the coordinated matrix...

Comment: Where have you got your transformation matrix from? [Image Registration documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/images/image-registration.html) implies that output is always one of three types of geometric transformation object, each of which documents the meaning of its transformation matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure about the features of the app, however if you have all the coordinates, you can apply some transformation matrices like rotation and inverse matrices inorder to obtain the new coordinates: -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: Can imwarp be used to apply transformation matrix to the coordinate matrix? I though imwarp can only be used to image files...

Comment: `T*p` should work to transform the coordinates. Can you post a [mcve] and show us where this is going wrong?

Comment: multiply coordinates could work if I want the coordinates under the same coordinate system, however, I want to obtain the coordinate of the coordinate system of the registered image. An example is added to the question description.